# Произвольное количество потоков (jthread)

Tags: c++, c++20

Требуется создать произвольное количество jthread-потоков. Определяя их количество во время работы программы.

Нашел множество подобных пример:

```
void spawnThreads(int n) {

    jthread threads[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = jthread(foo, i);
    }

}
```

Они оказались заведомо не рабочими, т.к cpp запрещает создавать массивы не определенного размера. После чего я использовал динамический массив, заменив первую строку на:

```
jthread* threads = new jthread[n]{};
```

Теперь, потоки запускаются но программа не дожидается их выполнения, просто закрываясь.
Если б это были thread, такое поведение было бы ожидаемым из-за отсутствия thread#.join() в коде. Но jthread не требуют операции join() и я в как новичок в замешательстве.

Comment: ну так Вы ничего не дали потокам делать. А раз нет чего делать, то они и закрываются. Дайте им любой код, хоть sleep и все будет ок. "cpp запрещает создавать массивы не определенного размера" - а как Вы себе представляете? это в принципе невозможно в любом языке. Но возможно, Вам нужен std::vector?

Comment: @KoVadim у потоков есть функция foo(), которая в бесконечном цикле занимается своими задачами. Я умышлено не стал добавлять ее сюда, т.к это лишний код для вопроса.

Comment: а давайте без "умышленного искажения кода"?

Comment: @KoVadim , в моем примере я использовал функцию foo(), она содержала бесконечный цикл печатающий номер итерации в консоль. Я действительно, не понимаю при чем тут искажение кода, т.к функция абсолютно не имеет значения в данному контексте.

Comment: ок, печатает она. И что дальше случается? она перестает печатать? как именно Вы поняли, что у Вас работает не так, как нужно?

Comment: ага, Ваша программа просто закрывается. Ну это и ожидаемо - главному потоку больше нечего делать. Вот он и закрывается, а без главного потока второстепенным сложно работать. Либо добавьте пустой цикл, либо join на нужные потоки в главном и все будет так, как хочется

Comment: Как я уже сказал, в вопросе, программа завешает свое выполнение(код 0), не дожидаясь завершения всех созданных потоков (jthread).

Comment: @KoVadim , все верно, но Jthread в отличии от thread согласно документации не должен требовать join(). И собственно не требуется, если использовать обычный массив указывая его размер вручную.

Comment: ну так основной поток завершается или нет?

Comment: @KoVadim , на сколько я могу судить исходя из своих скудных знаний в программировании на cxx : Основной поток завершается, не дожидаясь остальных. И происходит это только при использовании динамического массива в функции которая описана в вопросе. А ожидать основной поток потоки jthread обязан, и делает это в случае указанном выше в моем комментарии(при использовании не дин.масива).

Comment: *"Теперь, потоки запускаются но программа не дожидается их выполнения, просто закрываясь."* - приводите [mcve]

Comment: @user7860670 Нашел в интернете онлайн компилятор, и залил туда минимальный воспроизводимый пример https://onlinegdb.com/0RXQ9Jbq6

Comment: я уже ниже все расписал. а userXXXXX (лень вбивать)  просто не читал, ему нужен хороший, красивый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Динамический массив при выходе за пределы видимости не будет просто так вызывать деструкторы своих элементов. А если деструкторы никто не вызывает, то ничего не останавливает код "бежать дальше". А дальше только "на выход". И все потоки просто не успевают отработать. И достаточно вызвать их вручную

```
void spawnThreads(int n)
{
    std::jthread* threads = new std::jthread[n]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = std::jthread(foo, i);
    }
    delete[] threads; // ключевая строка!!!!
}
```

и вот этот `delete[]` в конце вызовет деструкторы и по факту вызовет `join`.

> т.к cpp запрещает создавать массивы не определенного размера.

вот не знаю, почему, но это очень очень популярная тема. А когда говоришь "вот есть `std::vector` - все почему то ворочают носом и говорят "ну это же не с++, это же библиотека". Но нет, STL это и есть часть языка. Просто ее аккуратно отделили. Поэтому, `std::vector`, `std::list` и десятки других классов - это и есть  с++, а не "какая то левая библиотека, написанная Степановым".

И теперь код стает простеньким и красивым.

```
void spawnThreads3(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::jthread> th;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        th.emplace_back(foo, i);
    }
}
```

я применил `emplace_back` для красоты:) Но можно было бы и так

```
th.push_back(std::jthread{foo, i});
```